Oracle PL/SQL collection vs global temporary table
I have a large external data file with 500k records  that I need to load to  Oracle 19c database while applying business logic to each row as it is being loaded. During loading some rows in destination tables may need to be updated or deleted. For each row in the input data as it is being processed, a status flag need to be updated if the row is not processed for any data validation errors.
Trying to understand whether I should use the Oracle global temporary tables or PL/SQL collections ( arrays or nested tables ) for this row by row processes. Also considered merge but not sure if merge is ideal in this situation.

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: details of the structure of the external data file; the logic that you want to apply during loading; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment your question is too generic to be able to answer; you need to provide a concrete problem for it to be solvable.

Are you sure either of these are appropriate?  If you're trying to load half a million rows and trying to implement a bunch of business logic, I'd wager that you want to load the data into a permanent table where you retain the data for some number of days in order to debug issues when they inevitably occur.  Otherwise, that status flag you want will disappear when the session that loads the data completes.
